# How to use the commands in Root after creating a new user in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, nvm

I have created a new user using `useradd MyUsername` and have given him "sudo" privilege. However, I noticed that I couldn't use the commands I have installed in root with this user.

For example:

**In root :** `nvm current` will show me the current nvm version

**In the User :** The same command line will give this result : `bash: nvm: command not found`

I'm using CentOS 7 (I believe). Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this ? Or do I need to download the libraries again in order to use them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nvm` is intended as a PER-USER script, as stated [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#about).
It is cloned and installed into the home-directory of each individual user.
Therefore, you need to install it again by following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script).

For other commands, please check that your `PATH` is correct, or if the command is also installed on a per-user basis like `nvm`.

Comment: I have tried this method, but i'm getting this error: "You have $NVM_DIR set to "/root/.nvm", but that directory does not exist. Check your profile files and environment."

I tried running it as sudo but i'm getting a timeout error with github. Any fix ?

Comment: Simply run `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash` as a normal user (not root) and without `sudo`. With the same user run `source ~/.bashrc`, again without sudo. If `github` is timing out, please check that github is not blocked.

Comment: You're right. Although, I did "unset NVM_DIR" from the root user and when I ran again the commands it worked. Thank you @Mime

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the relevant paths are exported.

While using the root user, you can find out where the nvm bin is using `which nvm`. For example, `/usr/local/bin/nvm`. Knowing this, ensure that the path before the nvm is exported in the path, in this example, `/usr/local/bin`.

You can add the following to the end of the correct file (see below).
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. What this is doing is that it is adding `/usr/local/bin` to the start of the PATH.

You can find out what shell you're running using `echo $0`.

If it is `zsh` you should examine the `.zshrc` file and ensure that the correct paths are exported.

If it is `bash` you should examine either `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` to ensure the same.